# Linear isoparametrics with dual finite elements

Tags: polyhedra, finite-differences, duality-theorems, polytopes, finite-element-method

[image]
The subject presented here is some content of the Wikipedia page about
[Platonic solid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid)s
combined with my own experience on Finite Elements.
To start with the 
latter, there is a standard piece of Finite Element theory concerning
[triangles](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541926/converting-triangles-to-isosceles-equilateral-or-right/542684#542684) on MSE.
The concept of *isoparametrics* is introduced herein. A reference to
the same theory is found in: 
[Is there any equation for triangle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544559/is-there-any-equation-for-triangle/544682#544682) (MSE).

 So far so good for 2-D. In three dimensions the analogue of a triangle is
a tetrahedron. Let the *parent tetrahedron* have vertices (Finite Element
"nodes") that are numbered as follows:
$$
   (0) = (0,0,0) \quad ; \quad (1) = (1,0,0) \quad ; \quad
   (2) = (0,1,0) \quad ; \quad (3) = (0,0,1)
$$
Then any function with the parent tetrahedron can be interpolated as:
$$
   f(\xi,\eta,\zeta) = (1-\xi-\eta-\zeta)f_0 + \xi\,f_1 + \eta\,f_2 + \zeta\,f_3
$$
*Isoparametrics* means that the same interpolation holds for the (global)
coordinates as well:
$$
   x = (1-\xi-\eta-\zeta)x_0 + \xi \, x_1 + \eta \, x_2 + \zeta \, x_3 \\
   y = (1-\xi-\eta-\zeta)y_0 + \xi \, y_1 + \eta \, y_2 + \zeta \, y_3 \\
   z = (1-\xi-\eta-\zeta)z_0 + \xi \, z_1 + \eta \, z_2 + \zeta \, z_3
$$
From this the local parameters $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ can eventually be solved and
expressed in the global coordinates (which is not common practice, though).

Another frequently used Finite Element is the quadrilateral in 2-D or, quite
analogously in 3-D: the hexahedron. The nodes of our parent element are:
$$
   (1) = (-1,-1,-1) \quad ; \quad 
   (2) = (+1,-1,-1) \quad ; \quad 
   (3) = (-1,+1,-1) \quad ; \quad 
   (4) = (+1,+1,-1) \quad ; \quad
   (5) = (-1,-1,+1) \quad ; \quad 
   (6) = (+1,-1,+1) \quad ; \quad 
   (7) = (-1,+1,+1) \quad ; \quad 
   (8) = (+1,+1,+1)
$$
Then any function $h$ at the parent $h$exahedron can be interpolated as:
$$
   h(\xi,\eta,\zeta) = \frac{1}{8}(1-\xi)(1-\eta)(1-\zeta) h_1
                      + \frac{1}{8}(1+\xi)(1-\eta)(1-\zeta) h_2
                      + \frac{1}{8}(1-\xi)(1+\eta)(1-\zeta) h_3
                      + \frac{1}{8}(1+\xi)(1+\eta)(1-\zeta) h_4
                      + \frac{1}{8}(1-\xi)(1-\eta)(1+\zeta) h_5
                      + \frac{1}{8}(1+\xi)(1-\eta)(1+\zeta) h_6
                      + \frac{1}{8}(1-\xi)(1+\eta)(1+\zeta) h_7
                      + \frac{1}{8}(1+\xi)(1+\eta)(1+\zeta) h_8
$$
Note that this interpolation, in general, is *not linear*. And it's not so easy anymore to solve for the global coordinates ( by substituting $h = x,y,z$ ).

The following is a possible generalization of a finite element which was
questioned about in:
[Understand 1D FEM solution using quadratics elements](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548856/understand-1d-fem-solution-using-quadratics-elements/548960#548960) (MSE).
In three dimensions we have the quite common *Finite Difference Star*,
which is a *not so common* Finite Element, namely an *octahedron*
augmented with the origin as an additional node $(0)$: 
$$
    (0) = (0,0,0) \quad ; \quad
    (1) = (-1,0,0) \quad ; \quad
    (2) = (+1,0,0) \quad ; \quad
    (3) = (0,-1,0) \quad ; \quad
    (4) = (0,+1,0) \quad ; \quad
    (5) = (0,0,-1) \quad ; \quad
    (6) = (0,0,+1)
$$
Then any function $s$ with the parent octahedron (F.D. $s$tar) can be
interpolated as:
$$
   s(\xi,\eta,\zeta) = (1 - \xi^2 - \eta^2 - \zeta^2) s_0
                      + \frac{1}{2}\xi (\xi-1) s_1
                      + \frac{1}{2}\xi (\xi+1) s_2
                      + \frac{1}{2}\eta (\eta-1) s_3
                      + \frac{1}{2}\eta (\eta+1) s_4
                      + \frac{1}{2}\zeta (\zeta-1) s_5
                      + \frac{1}{2}\zeta (\zeta+1) s_6
$$
But now
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid#Dual_polyhedra) is consulted and the following is read in the chapter **Dual polyhedra**:

- The tetrahedron is self-dual (i.e. its dual is another tetrahedron).
- The cube and the octahedron form a dual pair.

Therefore let's construct first the dual of an arbitrary octahedron, which is
not quite an arbitrary hexahedron:
$$
h_1 = (s_1 + s_3 + s_5)/3 \quad ; \quad 
h_2 = (s_2 + s_3 + s_5)/3 \quad ; \quad 
h_3 = (s_1 + s_4 + s_5)/3 \quad ; \quad 
h_4 = (s_2 + s_4 + s_5)/3 \quad ; \quad 
h_5 = (s_1 + s_3 + s_6)/3 \quad ; \quad 
h_6 = (s_2 + s_3 + s_6)/3 \quad ; \quad 
h_7 = (s_1 + s_4 + s_6)/3 \quad ; \quad 
h_8 = (s_2 + s_4 + s_6)/3
$$
Substitute this into the abovementioned formula for $h(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$
and then simplify.
The outcome (with a little help from Maple) is, to my great surprise:
$$
  \frac{1}{6}\left[\, (s_1 + s_2 + s_3 + s_4 + s_5 + s_6)
    + (s_2 - s_1)\,\xi + (s_4 - s_3)\,\eta + (s_6 - s_5)\,\zeta\, \right]
$$
*The interpolation with the **dual** hexahedron
of an arbitrary octahedron is **linear***. Because of the ispoarametrics ( substitute $h=x,y,z$ ), it
also means that the coordinates of the dual are far from arbitrary - but we did
already know that, didn't we?

The other way around, we construct the dual of an arbitrary hexahedron, which
is (not quite) an arbitrary octahedron:
$$
s_1 = (h_1 + h_3 + h_5 + h_7)/4 \quad ; \quad 
s_2 = (h_2 + h_4 + h_6 + h_8)/4 \\
s_3 = (h_1 + h_2 + h_5 + h_6)/4 \quad ; \quad 
s_4 = (h_3 + h_4 + h_7 + h_8)/4 \\
s_5 = (h_1 + h_2 + h_3 + h_4)/4 \quad ; \quad 
s_6 = (h_5 + h_6 + h_7 + h_8)/4 \\
s_0 = (s_1 + s_2 + s_3 + s_4 + s_5 + s_6)/6
$$
Substitute this into the abovementioned expression for $s(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ and simplify.
The outcome (with a little help from Maple) is, again to my surprise:
$$
  \frac{1}{8}\left[ \,( h_1+h_2+h_3+h_4+h_5+h_6+h_7+h_8) \\
                  + (-h_1+h_2-h_3+h_4-h_5+h_6-h_7+h_8)\xi \\
                  + (-h_1-h_2+h_3+h_4-h_5-h_6+h_7+h_8)\eta \\
                  + (-h_1-h_2-h_3-h_4+h_5+h_6+h_7+h_8)\zeta \,\right]
$$
*The interpolation with the **dual** octahedron
of an arbitrary hexahedron is **linear** again*.

At last, according to
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid#Higher_dimensions):

*In all dimensions higher than four, there are only three convex regular
polytopes: the simplex, the hypercube, and the cross-polytope. In three
dimensions, these coincide with the tetrahedron, the cube, and the octahedron.*
 Where the (self-dual, linear) simplex may be considered as a trivial case.

**Question.** In all dimensions higher than three, does the isoparametric
transformation give a *linear interpolation* for an arbitrary function
discretized at the *dual* polytope of a "finite element" with the hypercube or the
cross-polytope as a parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to overwhelming lack of interest I've received a Tumbleweed badge for this question.
Therefore I'm trying to answer it myself. The question will be
referred to as the **Dual = Linear conjecture** . Disclaimer: the following is only
a *partial answer*, because a general proof for dual polytopes in a space of
dimension $N$ is still lacking.
The polytopes are defined in a space of dimension $N$. The (isoparametric) Cartesian
coordinates in this space are $(c_1,c_2, \cdots ,c_N)$ . Input for Maple is generated
by a Pascal program, i.e. by employing brute force Computer Algebra. Sample Maple input is shown for three dimensional space $(N=3)$. We have two cases:

- the HyperCube as the dual polytope of the PolyStar
- the PolyStar as the dual polytope of the HyperCube

First case: the HyperCube as the dual polytope of the PolyStar. The following steps
have been taken in order to obtain an answer.

1. Define the $(2N+1)$ *shape functions* $S_k$ of the (normed) PolyStar:

   ```
   S0 := 1-c1^2-c2^2-c3^2;
   S1 := c1*(c1-1)/2;
   S2 := c1*(c1+1)/2;
   S3 := c2*(c2-1)/2;
   S4 := c2*(c2+1)/2;
   S5 := c3*(c3-1)/2;
   S6 := c3*(c3+1)/2;
   ```
2. Define the interpolation $g$ of the function values $g_k$ at the vertices of the PolyStar:

   ```
   g := g0*S0+g1*S1+g2*S2+g3*S3+g4*S4+g5*S5+g6*S6;
   ```
3. Evaluate the interpolation $g$ at the vertices of the dual element of the PolyStar, being the (normed) HyperCube, resulting in values $f_k$:

   ```
   f1 := eval(g,{c1=-1,c2=-1,c3=-1});
   f2 := eval(g,{c1=+1,c2=-1,c3=-1});
   f3 := eval(g,{c1=-1,c2=+1,c3=-1});
   f4 := eval(g,{c1=+1,c2=+1,c3=-1});
   f5 := eval(g,{c1=-1,c2=-1,c3=+1});
   f6 := eval(g,{c1=+1,c2=-1,c3=+1});
   f7 := eval(g,{c1=-1,c2=+1,c3=+1});
   f8 := eval(g,{c1=+1,c2=+1,c3=+1});
   ```
4. Define the $(2^N)$ *shape functions* $H_k$ and the function $f$ interpolating the
   values $f_k$ at the vertices of the dual (normed) HyperCube:

   ```
   H1 := (1-c1)/2*(1-c2)/2*(1-c3)/2;
   H2 := (1+c1)/2*(1-c2)/2*(1-c3)/2;
   H3 := (1-c1)/2*(1+c2)/2*(1-c3)/2;
   H4 := (1+c1)/2*(1+c2)/2*(1-c3)/2;
   H5 := (1-c1)/2*(1-c2)/2*(1+c3)/2;
   H6 := (1+c1)/2*(1-c2)/2*(1+c3)/2;
   H7 := (1-c1)/2*(1+c2)/2*(1+c3)/2;
   H8 := (1+c1)/2*(1+c2)/2*(1+c3)/2;
   f := f1*H1+f2*H2+f3*H3+f4*H4+f5*H5+f6*H6+f7*H7+f8*H8;
   ```
5. At last, let Maple do some work:

   ```
   sort(simplify(f));
   ```

   Resulting in:$$
   -1/2\,{\it c1}\,{\it g1}+1/2\,{\it c1}\,{\it g2}-1/2\,{\it c2}\,{\it 
   g3}+1/2\,{\it c2}\,{\it g4}-1/2\,{\it c3}\,{\it g5}+1/2\,{\it c3}\,{
   \it g6}-2\,{\it g0}+1/2\,{\it g1}+1/2\,{\it g2}+1/2\,{\it g3}+1/2\,{
   \it g4}+1/2\,{\it g5}+1/2\,{\it g6}$$
   By visual inspection, we see that the result is indeed *linear* in the $c_k$ coordinates.

Second case: the PolyStar as the dual polytope of the HyperCube.
The following steps have been taken in order to obtain an answer.

1. Define the $(2^N)$ *shape functions* $H_k$ of the (normed) Hypercube.
2. And the function $f$ interpolating the values $f_k$ at its vertices: see above.
3. Evaluate the interpolation $f$ at the vertices of the dual element of the HyperCube, which is the (normed) PolyStar, resulting in values $g_k$:

   ```
   g0 := eval(f,{c1=0,c2=0,c3=0});
   g1 := eval(f,{c1=-1,c2=0,c3=0});
   g2 := eval(f,{c1=+1,c2=0,c3=0});
   g3 := eval(f,{c1=0,c2=-1,c3=0});
   g4 := eval(f,{c1=0,c2=+1,c3=0});
   g5 := eval(f,{c1=0,c2=0,c3=-1});
   g6 := eval(f,{c1=0,c2=0,c3=+1});
   ```

   Define the $(2N+1)$ *shape functions* $S_k$ and the function $g$ interpolating the
   values $g_k$ at the vertices of the dual (normed) PolyStar: see above.

   At last, let Maple do some work:

   ```
   sort(simplify(g));
   ```

   Resulting in:$$
   -1/8\,{\it c1}\,{\it f1}+1/8\,{\it c1}\,{\it f2}-1/8\,{\it c1}\,{\it 
   f3}+1/8\,{\it c1}\,{\it f4}-1/8\,{\it c1}\,{\it f5}+1/8\,{\it c1}\,{
   \it f6}-1/8\,{\it c1}\,{\it f7}+1/8\,{\it c1}\,{\it f8}-1/8\,{\it c2}
   \,{\it f1}-1/8\,{\it c2}\,{\it f2}+1/8\,{\it c2}\,{\it f3}+1/8\,{\it 
   c2}\,{\it f4}-1/8\,{\it c2}\,{\it f5}-1/8\,{\it c2}\,{\it f6}+1/8\,{
   \it c2}\,{\it f7}+1/8\,{\it c2}\,{\it f8}-1/8\,{\it c3}\,{\it f1}-1/8
   \,{\it c3}\,{\it f2}-1/8\,{\it c3}\,{\it f3}-1/8\,{\it c3}\,{\it f4}+1
   /8\,{\it c3}\,{\it f5}+1/8\,{\it c3}\,{\it f6}+1/8\,{\it c3}\,{\it f7}
   +1/8\,{\it c3}\,{\it f8}+1/8\,{\it f1}+1/8\,{\it f2}+1/8\,{\it f3}+1/8
   \,{\it f4}+1/8\,{\it f5}+1/8\,{\it f6}+1/8\,{\it f7}+1/8\,{\it f8}
   $$
   By visual inspection, we see that the result is again *linear* in the $c_k$ coordinates.

In this way, I've proved the **Dual = Linear conjecture** for spaces with dimension $N = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8$.
Then Maple gives up. And me too, for the moment being.
Here is the program that generates the input for Maple:

```
program maple;

type
  punt = array of integer;

function Letterlijk(nr : integer) : string;
{
  Convert Natural to String
}
const
  cijfer : string = '0123456789';
var
  no,t,tel,wel : integer;
  vgl : string;
  c : char;
begin
  no := nr;
  tel := 0;
{ Analysis }
  vgl := '';
  while no > 0 do
  begin
    c := cijfer[(no mod 10) + 1];
    vgl := vgl + c;
    no := no div 10;
    tel := tel + 1;
  end;
  wel := tel div 2;
  for t := 0 to wel-1 do
  begin
    c := vgl[t+1];
    vgl[t+1] := vgl[tel-t];
    vgl[tel-t] := c;
  end;
  if vgl = '' then vgl := '0';
  Letterlijk := vgl;
end;

function twee(power : integer) : integer;
{
  Compute 2^power
}
var
  k : integer;
  h : integer;
begin
  h := 1;
  for k := 1 to power do
    h := h shl 1;
  twee := h;
end;

function crd_H(nr,N : integer) : punt;
{
  Node Number -> Hypercube Vertex Coordinates
}
var
  P : punt;
  h,k : integer;
begin
  h := nr-1;
  SetLength(P,N);
  for k := 1 to N do
  begin
    P[k-1] := 2*(h and 1)-1;
    h := h shr 1;
  end;
  crd_H := P;
end;

function crd_S(nr,N : integer) : punt;
{
  Node Number -> PolyStar Vertex Coordinates
}
var
  P : punt;
  b,v,k : integer;
begin
  SetLength(P,N);
  for k := 1 to N do
  begin
    P[k-1] := 0;
  end;
  if nr > 0 then
  begin
    b := (nr-1) div 2;
    v := (nr-1) mod 2;
    P[b] := 2*v-1;
  end;
  crd_S := P;
end;

procedure shapes_H(N : integer);
{
  HyperCube Shape Functions
}
var
  k,h,i,D : integer;
  c,s : string;
begin
  D := twee(N);
  for i := 1 to D do
  begin
    h := i-1;
    s := ' := ';
    for k := 0 to N-1 do
    begin
      c := Letterlijk(k+1);
      if (h and 1) = 0
      then s := s + '(1-c' + c + ')/2*'
      else s := s + '(1+c' + c + ')/2*';
      h := h shr 1;
    end;
    Writeln('H',i,Copy(s,1,Length(s)-1),';');
  end;
  s := '';
  for k := 1 to D do
  begin
    c := Letterlijk(k);
    s := s + 'f' + c + '*H' + c + '+';
  end;
  Writeln('f := ',Copy(s,1,Length(s)-1),';');
end;

procedure shapes_S(N : integer);
{
  PolyStar Shape Functions
}
var
  k,i : integer;
  c,s : string;
begin
  s := ' := 1';
  for k := 1 to N do
  begin
    c := Letterlijk(k);
    s := s + '-c' + c + '^2';
  end;
  s := s + ';';
  Writeln('S0',s);
  for i := 1 to 2*N do
  begin
    s := ' := ';
    c := Letterlijk((i+1) div 2);
    if (i mod 2) = 1
    then s := s + 'c' + c + '(c' + c + '-1)/2;'
    else s := s + 'c' + c + '(c' + c + '+1)/2;';
    Writeln('S',i,s);
  end;
  s := 'g := ';
  for k := 0 to 2*N do
  begin
    c := Letterlijk(k);
    s := s + 'g' + c + '*S' + c + '+';
  end;
  Writeln(Copy(s,1,Length(s)-1),';');
end;

procedure test_H(N : integer);
{
  Dual = Linear test for
  HyperCube in PolyStar
}
var
  k,D,i : integer;
  s,c : string;
  P : punt;
begin
  shapes_S(N);

  SetLength(P,N);
  D := twee(N);
  for k := 1 to D do
  begin
    c := Letterlijk(k);
    s := 'f' + c + ' := eval(g,{';
    P := crd_H(k,N);
    for i := 1 to N do
    begin
      if P[i-1] = -1 then c := '-1';
      if P[i-1] = +1 then c := '+1';
      s := s + 'c' + Letterlijk(i) + '=' + c + ',';
    end;
    c := Letterlijk(N);
    Writeln(Copy(s,1,Length(s)-1),'});');
  end;

  shapes_H(N);
  Writeln('sort(simplify(f));');
end;

procedure test_S( N : integer);
{
  Dual = Linear test for
  PolyStar in HyperCube
}
var
  k,i : integer;
  s,c : string;
  P : punt;
begin
  shapes_H(N);

  s := 'g0 := eval(f,{';
  for i := 1 to N do
    s := s + 'c' + Letterlijk(i) + '=0,';
  Writeln(Copy(s,1,Length(s)-1),'});');
  SetLength(P,0);
  for k := 1 to 2*N do
  begin
    c := Letterlijk(k);
    s := 'g' + c + ' := eval(f,{';
    P := crd_S(k,N);
    for i := 1 to N do
    begin
      if P[i-1] =  0 then c :=  '0';
      if P[i-1] = -1 then c := '-1';
      if P[i-1] = +1 then c := '+1';
      s := s + 'c' + Letterlijk(i) + '=' + c + ',';
    end;
    c := Letterlijk(N);
    Writeln(Copy(s,1,Length(s)-1),'});');
  end;

  shapes_S(N);
  Writeln('sort(simplify(g));');
end;

begin
{ test_H(8); }
{ test_S(9); }
  test_H(3);
  Writeln;
  test_S(3);
end.
```