# Quadratic shape functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, finite-element-method

I am given a differential equation in $x \in [0, L]$

\begin{align}
   \lambda\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + q = 0
\end{align}

where $q = a + bx$. The solution is subject to the boundary conditions

\begin{align}
   u(0) = 0 \ \ and \ \ \lambda\frac{du}{dx}\bigg |_{x = L} = 0 
\end{align}

Now I want to find an approximate solution using a three-node element. The shape function is given as

\begin{align}
   \mathbf{N} =
   \begin{bmatrix}
      -\frac{1}{2}s(1-s) & (1-s^2) & \frac{1}{2}s(1+s) 
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

The task is the solve the system but what I am wondering is what I need to calculate in order to do this? For example I have seen equations such as

\begin{align}
   \mathbf{k} = \int_{-1}^1\mathbf{B^TBJ}ds 
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
   \mathbf{m} = \int_{-1}^1\mathbf{N^TNJ}ds
\end{align}

But how should I use this information in order to achieve the final solution?

Comment: Two remarks. (1) As an inexperienced user, I would rather start with __linear__ instead of quadratic __elements__. For the problem at hand, this perfectly possible. (2) Related: be extremely cautious with higher order (i.e. non-linear) elements, because they easily exhibit spurious behavior. As is clearly exemplified in : [Understand 1D FEM solution using quadratics elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548856/understand-1d-fem-solution-using-quadratics-elements) . Unfortunately, my knowledge about FEM has become more rustier than I hoped for, so this is all for the moment being.

Comment: Related question & __answer__ @ : [Understanding Galerkin method of weighted residuals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741001/understanding-galerkin-method-of-weighted-residuals) ?

Comment: It's not really the quadratic functions that is my problem (the topic is a bit confussing, sorry), I just don't know how to approach the problem correctly. Like I don't know what I am suppossed to do with the differential equation

Comment: Doesn't the above comment with "Related question & __answer__" help? Actually, I've made sort of a copy and paste of a deleted answer to you for that answer.