# What is the difference between trial and test functions in the context of numerical integration?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

I know that in, for example, Galerkin's method we try to approximate the solution via a sum

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n} u_{j} a\left(e_{j}, e_{i}\right)
$$

with $a\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$ a bilinear form and $u_j$ are the test functions. However I have come across a sentence 'Each row of a Galerkin system matrix is associated with a locally supported test function, while each
matrix column is associated with a trial function. ' and I'm not sure what the trial functions are. Can anybody help or point me to a definition?

Comment: See [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/energy281/FiniteElementMethod.pdf). They use *trial functions* to name the functions in the space where the solution of the integral equation are found.

Answer (score 3):

Take a (good) look at this **Question & Answer @ MSE** :

- [Understanding Galerkin method of weighted residuals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741001/understanding-galerkin-method-of-weighted-residuals)

Then somewhere in the answer you will find the following expression:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} f_1 & f_2 & f_3 & f_4 & f_5 & \cdots \end{bmatrix} \times \\
\begin{bmatrix} E_{0,0}^{(1)} & E_{0,1}^{(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
E_{1,0}^{(1)} & E_{1,1}^{(1)}+E_{0,0}^{(2)} & E_{0,1}^{(2)} & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & E_{1,0}^{(2)} & E_{1,1}^{(2)}+E_{0,0}^{(3)} & E_{0,1}^{(3)} & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & E_{1,0}^{(3)} & E_{1,1}^{(3)}+E_{0,0}^{(4)} & E_{0,1}^{(4)} & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ T_4 \\ T_5 \\ \cdots \end{bmatrix}
$$
In short:
$$
\sum_i\sum_j f_i\,S_{ij}\,T_j
$$
So $f_i$ is the discretization of a *test* function $f(x)$ and it is associated with a matrix *row* $(i)$;
$T_j$ is the discretization of a *trial* function $T(x)$ and it is associated with a matrix *column* $(j)$.