# Shape function in Finite Element Method

Tags: finite-element-method

Why is it that the choice of polynomial for 6-nodes rectangular element(linear in sides 1 and 3, quadratic in sides 2 and 4) in FEM does not follow normal pascal triangle regular arrangement? i.e $u=c_1+c_2x+c_3y+c_4xy+c_5xy^2+c_6x^2y$ .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

[image]
See above picture: there are only (linear) line segments in vertical direction.
And because of the three nodal points, there are two quadratic elements in horizontal direction. A reference for the latter:

- [**Understand 1D FEM solution using quadratics elements**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548856/understand-1d-fem-solution-using-quadratics-elements/2572297#2572297)

Therefore the interpolation must be linear in $\,y\,$ and quadratic in $\,x\,$. According to a Cartesian product:
$$
(1,y) \times (1,x,x^2) = (1,x,x^2,y,yx,yx^2)
$$
Mind that your term with $y^2$ is absent now and two terms with $x^2$ are present.
So the correct interpolation may be formulated as:
$$
u=c_1+c_2x+c_3y+c_4xy+\color{red}{c_5x^2}+c_6x^2y
$$