# Reference request: matricial representation of conics (and quadrics too)

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, conic-sections, book-recommendation, quadrics

Can anybody please provide me some references where to read the complete passages / proofs about how and why the matricial representation of conics and quadrics are useful and they work?

I mean, the theory is rather simple. We can classify conics by looking at the three invariants.
Where can I learn how all of this is born?

Thank you!

P.s. Before anyone says it: wikipedia's references are not useful/enough.

Comment: If you want the history, go to science history!

Comment: @trula Sorry, not exactly the history. I meant the proof, or a detailed explanation with the passages.

Comment: See, for instance, [this recent answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4494799/409), which gives the equation of a conic based on the focus-directrix definition and a few geometric parameters. Multiplying equation $(2)$ by an unspecified constant $k$ gives the generic second-degree equation. You can substitute the resulting coefficients into results you're seeing (say, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections)) to confirm their validity.

Comment: Try chapter 9 of Richter-Gebert *Perspectives on Projective Geometry*